# Requested Path JAX-RS

Tags: java, path, jersey, uri, jax-rs

how can I write the following in correct Java?:

```
@GET
@Path("{blah}/{blahh}")
public String getAnything(@PathParam("blah") String blah, 
                          @PathParam("blahh") String blahh,
                          @Path String path) {
  return "<a href=" + path + ">Hi</a>";
}
```

I want to get the whole requested Path in a variable. How do I do this? I'm using Jersey, JAX-RS and Tomcat.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should add the `UriInfo` parameter:

```
@GET
@Path("{blah}/{blahh}")
public String getAnything(@PathParam("blah") String blah, 
                          @PathParam("blahh") String blahh,
                          @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
  return "<a href='" + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "'>Hi</a>";
}
```